# looping in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a vba code I'm creating. I have an excel file where in the first 3 columns I have some information such as part/number, etc, quantity requested. Then in the same sheet in other columns I have more data where I might or might not have the same part/numbers as in the firsts columns, along with more information. The idea is to go part/number by part/number in the first columns and check if it is present in the last columns(or data set) and check if the second data set satisfies the quantity requested requirement from the first data set and if not move down to the next row as in the second data set there might be duplicates for the same part/number since they have different prices, projects, etc. So the idea is, if I have in the second data set the quantity needed from the first, copy those values into different cells and create a sum, so I will know the total at the end. I did some coding but I'm getting errors as I'm very new to vba. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

column A is the part/number of the first data set, and C the quantity needed/requested
column AP is the part/number of the second data set, and AQ the quantity available

```
Sub ExitFor_Loop()

    Dim i, j, qty   As Integer
    Dim mySum       As Double
    mySum = 0

    For i = 2 To 374
        qty = Range("C" & i).Value
        For j = 2 To 13672
            If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value Then
                Do
                    If qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value Then
                        Range("BC" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
                        Range("BD" & j).Value = Range("AT" & j).Value
                        Range("BE" & j).Value = Range("AQ" & j).Value
                        Range("BF" & j).Value = Range("AV" & j).Value
                        Range("BG" & j).Value = Range("AW" & j).Value
                        Range("BH" & j).Value = Range("AX" & j).Value
                        Range("BI" & j).Value = Range("AY" & j).Value
                        Range("BJ" & j).Value = Range("AZ" & j).Value
                        mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
                        qty = qty - Range("AQ" & j).Value
                    Else
                        Range("BC" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
                        Range("BD" & j).Value = Range("AT" & j).Value
                        Range("BE" & j).Value = Range("AQ" & j).Value
                        Range("BF" & j).Value = Range("AV" & j).Value
                        Range("BG" & j).Value = Range("AW" & j).Value
                        Range("BH" & j).Value = Range("AX" & j).Value
                        Range("BI" & j).Value = Range("AY" & j).Value
                        Range("BJ" & j).Value = Range("AZ" & j).Value
                        mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
                    End If

               Loop While (qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value  And ("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value)
            Next j
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: You should also know that this statement `Dim i, j, qty   As Integer` only declares `qty` as `Integer` type variable. `i` and `j` are declared as `Variant` type. In vba, you need to declare each variable independently and explicity. `Dim i as Integer, j as Integer, qty as Integer`

Comment: Which column is mySum to be written to ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below fixes the errors you've been getting. Would be helpful to have an example snip of data and requested operation to optimize the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExitFor_Loop()

Dim i, j, qty   As Integer
Dim mySum       As Double
mySum = 0

For i = 2 To 374
  qty = Range("C" & i).Value
    For j = 2 To 13672
      If Range("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value Then
        Do While (qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value And Range("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value)
            If qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value Then
                Range("BC" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
                Range("BD" & j).Value = Range("AT" & j).Value
                Range("BE" & j).Value = Range("AQ" & j).Value
                Range("BF" & j).Value = Range("AV" & j).Value
                Range("BG" & j).Value = Range("AW" & j).Value
                Range("BH" & j).Value = Range("AX" & j).Value
                Range("BI" & j).Value = Range("AY" & j).Value
                Range("BJ" & j).Value = Range("AZ" & j).Value
                mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
                qty = qty - Range("AQ" & j).Value
            Else
                Range("BC" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
                Range("BD" & j).Value = Range("AT" & j).Value
                Range("BE" & j).Value = Range("AQ" & j).Value
                Range("BF" & j).Value = Range("AV" & j).Value
                Range("BG" & j).Value = Range("AW" & j).Value
                Range("BH" & j).Value = Range("AX" & j).Value
                Range("BI" & j).Value = Range("AY" & j).Value
                Range("BJ" & j).Value = Range("AZ" & j).Value
                mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
            End If
         Loop
      End If
  Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a run time error 6 overflow at qty = Range("C" & i).Value

Comment: @Jonathan What is the largest number in column C, is it > 32,767 ?

Answer (score 0):

As well as the coding errors with missing `Range`

```
'Loop While (qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value  And ("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value)
Loop While (qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value  And Range("A" & i).Value = Range("AP" & j).Value)
```

and missing `End If` between `Loop` and `Next j`, the logic is flawed.

Inside the loop, the value of j does not change so the sum is calculated
using the price of the first item found regardless of the quantity available. The loop is not needed and should be removed.

Also where the quantity is less that those available, the price is calculated using the quantity available ( not quantity required) and the quantity required is unchanged.

```
If qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value Then
    ' range copy
    mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
    qty = qty - Range("AQ" & j).Value
Else
    ' range copy
    mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
End If
```

should be

```
If qty > Range("AQ" & j).Value Then
    ' range copy
    mySum = mySum + Range("AQ" & j).Value * Range("AV" & j).Value
    qty = qty - Range("AQ" & j).Value
Else
    ' range copy
    mySum = mySum + qty * Range("AV" & j).Value
    qty = 0
End If
```

Note the sum will be incorrect if the total quantity available is less than the quantity required.

These declaration would be better as `Long`

```
' Dim i, j, qty   As Integer  
Dim i as Long, j as Long, qty as Long
```

as it will fail if `qty > 32767`

This code writes the sum for each part into column D

```vb
Sub ExitFor_Loop2()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1" ' change as required

    Const COL_PART = "A"
    Const COL_QU = "C"
    Const COL_SUM = "D" ' sum for each part change as required

    Const COL_STOCKPART = "AP"
    Const COL_STOCKQU = "AQ"
    Const COL_STOCKPRICE = "AV"

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, iLastRow As Long
    Dim t0 As Single, count As Long
    t0 = Timer

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)

    Dim iQu As Long, dSum As Double, sPart As String
    Dim iStockRow As Long, iStockQu As Long, dStockPrice As Double
    Dim iLastStock As Long

    iLastStock = ws.Range(COL_STOCKPART & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    iLastRow = ws.Range(COL_PART & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    'Debug.Print iLastRow, iLastStock

    ' double loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For iRow = 2 To iLastRow

        sPart = ws.Cells(iRow, COL_PART)
        iQu = ws.Cells(iRow, COL_QU)
        dSum = 0

        For iStockRow = 2 To iLastStock

            ' matching part no
            If sPart = ws.Cells(iStockRow, COL_STOCKPART) Then

                iStockQu = ws.Cells(iStockRow, COL_STOCKQU) 'qu
                dStockPrice = ws.Cells(iStockRow, COL_STOCKPRICE) 'price

                With ws.Rows(iStockRow)
                   .Columns("BC") = sPart
                   .Columns("BD").Value = .Columns("AT").Value
                   .Columns("BE").Value = .Columns("AQ").Value
                   .Columns("BF:BJ").Value = .Columns("AV:AZ").Value
                End With

                If iQu > iStockQu Then

                    dSum = dSum + iStockQu * dStockPrice
                    iQu = iQu - iStockQu

                Else

                    dSum = dSum + iQu * dStockPrice
                    iQu = 0
                    iStockRow = iLastStock ' end search

                End If

            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next

        ' not enough stock
        If iQu > 0 Then
            MsgBox iQu & " items short for " & sPart, vbExclamation, "Part row " & iRow
            dSum = 0
        End If

        ws.Cells(iRow, COL_SUM) = dSum ' sum in coll E
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   MsgBox "Scanned col " & COL_PART & " to row " & iRow - 1, vbInformation, _
          count & " iterations completed in " & Format(Timer - t0, "0.00") & " secs"
End Sub
~~~
```